# Android - One button turns into two

Tags: android, button, android-activity

How can I create three buttons such that only the first appears, and once it is clicked it is replaced by two side-by-side buttons in it's place? These buttons should be centered.

[image: First button]

[image: Two buttons that appear once the entered button is pressed]

This is what I have so far:

```
<Button
            android:id="@+id/enter_button"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="@string/enter_button"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />


    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/buttons_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="30dp" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/clear_button"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:text="@string/clear_button"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/reserve_button"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="@string/reserve_button"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

But this causes the two side-by-side buttons to appear below the first one (not directly over it). I already know how to use setVisibility to make the enter button disappear.

Comment: `setVisibility()` method will help a lot

Answer (score 0):

It's simple.
The parent element is probably linearlayout. Change it to framelayout or add one if they are under the root element and it should work.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

put all 3 buttons in one horizontal linearlayout like below:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/buttons_layout"
    android:layout_width="368dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="30dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/enter_button"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="Enter"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/clear_button"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="@string/clear_button"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" 
        android:visibility="gone"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/reserve_button"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="@string/reserve_button"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

The last two button's visibility should be "Gone" and on "enter button" click , set their visibility to "Visible" and "enter" should be set to "Gone".

For centering the buttons, the problem is that you are using layout-gravity. Instead you should be using gravity to center children (see code above).

Note: Don't use setVisibility(Invisible), use setVisibility(Gone)